# compare a select option value and a value from URL

Tags: javascript

I have a select tag to choose categories, each option contain the category number as value.
The category number is in the URL string.
I'm trying to write a JS to check if the option value is the same as the category number in the URL and if so make the option selected. so far the script dosnot work.
What am I doing wrong?

here is the code:

```
function GetUrlValue(VarSearch){
    var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var VariableArray = SearchString.split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < VariableArray.length; i++){
        var KeyValuePair = VariableArray[i].split('=');
        if(KeyValuePair[0] === VarSearch){
            return KeyValuePair[1];
        }
    }
}
function compareValue(){
    var x = document.getElementById("selectcategory").length;
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++){
        var categNo = document.getElementById("selectcategory").options[i];
        var UrlValue1 = GetUrlValue('icid');
        if (categNo === UrlValue) {
            document.getElementById("selectcategory").options[i].selected = true;
        }
        alert(UrlValue1);
    }
}
```

if needed, I will send a link to the work.
if doing that with jquery is easier, i will be happey to learn.

thanx.

Comment: `document.getElementById("selectcategory").length` doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't know if it is a typo but you declare the variable `var UrlValue1 = ...` but then you compare `categNo === UrlValue` ...there isn't the **`1`** at the end of the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `categNo` should be the value of the corresponding option tag. Also it's better to cache select element and not requery DOM in the loop:

```
function compareValue() {

    var select = document.getElementById("selectcategory");
    var x = select.options.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        var categNo = document.getElementById("selectcategory").options[i].value;
        var UrlValue = GetUrlValue('icid');
        if (categNo === UrlValue) {
            select.options[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/dj7c6sdL/

Comment: your answer was realy helpful