# How to compare variable and check if it contains select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have variable and two selects on a page. I would like to check if variable contains any of the select options, if it does, I want to set it to selected true.

In this example, dropdown 1 option 'Webinar' and dropdown 2 option 'Transport Management' should be selected true.

```js
var query = "Webinar, Transport Management";

    $('select.select-dropdown option').each(function() {
        if (query.contains($(this).val())) {
            $(this).attr('selected', true);
        }
    });
```

```html
<div class="dropdowns-group">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <label for="test">Test</label>
    <select class="select-dropdown" name="test" id="test">
      <option value="">Show all</option>
      <option value="Webinar">Webinar</option>
      <option value="Lecture">Lecture</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <label for="test2">Test2</label>
    <select class="select-dropdown" name="test2" id="test2">
      <option value="">Show all</option>
      <option value="Transport Management">Transport Management</option>
      <option value="Teaching">Teaching</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you just looking for [the `includes()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) on a string?  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: What have you tried? We're not a free coding service. See [ask].

Comment: Apologies I just edited my question. I've been trying contains()

Comment: Thank you @David I edited my function with includes() and it's working now.

Comment: Since I am asked for more explanation in my answer, 
I would like you to provide more precision in your question: 
are all the terms on the query are **obligatory** present in **only one** of the `select > option` elements
, and is the **terms order** is the same as that of **selects list** ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [compare a select option value and a value from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097385/compare-a-select-option-value-and-a-value-from-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- split the *query* by `/, */` (comma followed by (zero or more) spaces
- use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to return an Option Element
- which value is in array by using [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const preselectTest = (query) => {
  const queryArr = query.split(/, */);
  const elsSelect = document.querySelectorAll("#test, #test2");
  elsSelect.forEach(elSelect => {
    const elsOptions = elSelect.querySelectorAll("option");
    const opt = [...elsOptions].find(elOpt => queryArr.includes(elOpt.value) );
    if (opt) elSelect.value = opt.value;
  });
};

const query = "Webinar, Transport Management";
preselectTest(query);
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <label for="test">Test</label>
  <select class="select-dropdown" name="test" id="test">
    <option value="">Show all</option>
    <option value="Webinar">Webinar</option>
    <option value="Lecture">Lecture</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <label for="test2">Test2</label>
  <select class="select-dropdown" name="test2" id="test2">
    <option value="">Show all</option>
    <option value="Foo Bar">Foo Bar</option>
    <option value="Transport Management">Transport Management</option>
    <option value="Teaching">Teaching</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: it's almost fine, you just forgot to add a `elSelect.selectedIndex = 0;`   to initialize the selects before searching...

Answer (score 0):

Not so hard a learn...

This snippet does exactly what the OP is asking:
-- setting the `selected` property to `true` on the corresponding `option` elements

```js
const query  = "Webinar, Transport Management".split(', ');

document.querySelector('#test').value  = query[0];  
document.querySelector('#test2').value = query[1];




/* ----- Control : -------*/
console.log( '-----test:' );
[...document.querySelector('#test').options].forEach( (opt,i) => 
  console.log( i, '--> selected:', opt.selected, '\t', opt.value ) );

console.log( '----test2:' );
[...document.querySelector('#test2').options].forEach( (opt,i) => 
  console.log( i, '--> selected:', opt.selected, '\t', opt.value ) );
```

```html
<select id="test">
  <option value=""        > Show all </option>
  <option value="Webinar" > Webinar  </option>
  <option value="Lecture" > Lecture  </option>
</select>

<select id="test2">
  <option value=""                     > Show all             </option>
  <option value="Transport Management" > Transport Management </option>
  <option value="Teaching"             > Teaching             </option>
</select>
```

otherwise, in the case where the values present in the query are not 100% reliable:

```js
setSelects( 'Webinar, Transport Management' );

function setSelects( query ) 
  {
  query = query.split(',').map(s=>s.trim());

  document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach( slct =>
    [...slct.options].forEach( opt => 
      opt.selected = (query.indexOf(opt.value) >= 0 )));
  }
```

```html
<select name="test">
  <option value=""        > Show all </option>
  <option value="Webinar" > Webinar  </option>
  <option value="Lecture" > Lecture  </option>
</select>

<select name="test2">
  <option value=""                     > Show all             </option>
  <option value="Transport Management" > Transport Management </option>
  <option value="Teaching"             > Teaching             </option>
</select>
```